# How to change bg color of column based on column values in HTML

Tags: html, shell, background-color

## Current script

I have a text file which get the server info whether UP/Down for a given time period with entries like:

```
Server1   UP   DOWN   UP   Down   UP   UP   Down
Server2  Down   UP   Down   Up    UP  Down   Down
```

Here is the shell script which converts the above text file to a HTML page.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html>\n<head>\n <style>\n table,th,td \n{\n border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<Body>\n<table><tr></tr> "
    }
    {
    print "<tr>"
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"
    }
    END{
    print "\n</table>\n</Body>\n</html>\n"
    }'  testresult.txt > /var/www/html/test.html
```

## Issue:

while converting the text contents to HTML, I need the  HTML cells background to be colored to RED when the entry is "Down" and to GREEN when server is "UP"

## Tried:

I have tried to include an If statement inside the for loop for matching the text values with UP/Down. But in vain.Could you please suggest where I am missing and is there any other way i could try?

Comment: could you write your shell "if command" here. you could easily solve it with js code, but if you do the if command right it should be easy if you give an style or class to the <td> element.

Comment: Hi @KOrroshSh: I tried to place if after the for loop as below:  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
if [ $i == " UP"] ..(then do actions)
        print "<td>" $i"</td>"
    print "</tr>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

    print "<td>" $i"</td>"
```

with

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)

    print "<td class = 'style" $i "'>" $i"</td>"
```

Then add to your css

```
.styleDown {background-color: red;}
.styleUP {background-color: green;}
```